# About cancel manually modify the routing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I set up a `rendererOptions` property.

```
var rendererOptions = {draggable: true};
```

And then instantiate a `DirectionsRenderer` object:

```
 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

Executive `directionsService.route()` method later, route has a small dot on the map, you can drag to modify the route.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
       directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

    }
  });
```

My question is how to cancel changes made on the route, delete dragged out of small dot.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `response` of `directionsService.route()` in a variable and call `directionsDisplay.setDirections()` with the stored variable as argument when you want to revert the changes.

Comment: Only use directionsDisplay.setDirections () method to restore the initial response results?

Comment: `directionsDisplay.setDirections(storedResponse);` , where storedResponse is the response retrieved in the callback of `directionsService.route()`